# NotSerializableException: unexpected

Tags: java, serialization

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try ( ObjectOutputStream output = 
        new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("object.dat")); ) {
      output.writeObject(new A());
    }
  }
}

class A implements Serializable {
  B b = new B();
}

class B { 
}
```

Why would a javaNotSerializableException occur in the following code?  Please try to be as simplistic as possible because my prorammming capabilities are not as well founded as I like them to be.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your (serializable) instance of `A` has a reference to an instance of `B`.  The `B` class is not serializable.  That means that the `A` instance cannot be serialized *despite* being declared as `Serializable`.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for `Serializable` says this:

> *"When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the `Serializable` interface. In this case the `NotSerializableException` will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object."*